# Combine UNION results into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME 
SELECT @dateFrom = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) 
SELECT TCD.DigitsDialed   AS [OriginalDigitsDialed], 
  A.EnterpriseName   AS [OriginalAgentEnterpriseName], 
  SG.EnterpriseName  AS [OriginalAgentSkillGroup],
    MS.EnterpriseName AS [OriginalScript],
  RCD.BeganRoutingDateTime [TransferDateTime],  
  RCD.DialedNumberString AS [TransferDestinationVDN]
FROM dbo.Termination_Call_Detail TCD 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM Route_Call_Detail 
      WHERE DateTime > @dateFrom) RCD 
     ON TCD.RouterCallKeyDay = RCD.RouterCallKeyDay 
      AND TCD.RouterCallKey = RCD.RouterCallKey 
      AND RCD.RouterCallKeySequenceNumber < TCD.RouterCallKeySequenceNumber 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Agent A 
     ON A.SkillTargetID = TCD.AgentSkillTargetID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Skill_Group SG 
     ON TCD.SkillGroupSkillTargetID = SG.SkillTargetID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Script S
         ON RCD.ScriptID = S.ScriptID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script MS
         ON S.MasterScriptID = MS.MasterScriptID
WHERE TCD.DateTime > @dateFrom 
    AND RCD.RequestType = '2'
  AND TCD.AgentSkillTargetID IS NOT NULL
  AND RCD.RouterCallKeyDay = '154514'
  AND RCD.RouterCallKey = '2556'
UNION
SELECT TCD.DigitsDialed   AS [OriginalDigitsDialed], 
  A.EnterpriseName   AS [OriginalAgentEnterpriseName], 
  SG.EnterpriseName  AS [OriginalAgentSkillGroup],
    MS.EnterpriseName AS [OriginalScript],
  RCD.BeganRoutingDateTime [TransferDateTime],  
  RCD.DialedNumberString AS [TransferDestinationVDN]
FROM dbo.Termination_Call_Detail TCD 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM Route_Call_Detail 
      WHERE DateTime > @dateFrom) RCD 
     ON TCD.RouterCallKeyDay = RCD.RouterCallKeyDay 
      AND TCD.RouterCallKey = RCD.RouterCallKey 
      AND RCD.RouterCallKeySequenceNumber < TCD.RouterCallKeySequenceNumber 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Agent A 
     ON A.SkillTargetID = TCD.AgentSkillTargetID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Skill_Group SG 
     ON TCD.SkillGroupSkillTargetID = SG.SkillTargetID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Script S
         ON RCD.ScriptID = S.ScriptID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Master_Script MS
         ON S.MasterScriptID = MS.MasterScriptID
WHERE TCD.DateTime > @dateFrom 
  AND TCD.CallDisposition IN ('28','29') 
    AND RCD.RequestType = '6'
  AND TCD.AgentSkillTargetID IS NOT NULL
  AND RCD.RouterCallKeyDay = '154514'
  AND RCD.RouterCallKey = '2556'
```

Right now, it returns two rows, but would like to put the returned results into one row. I've tried my best to implement what I've found on this site, but other posts are slightly different than mine and I think that adds challenges when I try to do it.

Expected results below

```
| OriginalDigitsDialed | OriginalAgentEnterpriseName | OriginalAgentSkillGroup | OriginalScript | TransferDateTime | TransferDestinationVDN | XferAgentEnterpriseName | XferAgentSkillGroup | XferScript |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1111111111             | John.Doe                    | Sales                   | SalesQueue     | 2024-01-18 11:00 | 8675309                | Jane.Doe                | Billing             | BillingQueue
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and **MINIMAL** don't show us complex production code. Build the smallest possible example which demonstrates the issue you are facing. (And ensure your sample data is table markdown not images).

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: Why do you have `LEFT JOIN`s to `RCD` when you require non-`NULL` values in the columns? When, for example, do you expect `RCD.RequestType = '2'` to be true if no row in `RCD` is found?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the data

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you... I've added the expected results. My apologizes, I'm not very proficient in SQL, I can stumble my way through it though.

Comment: @Dale That's a classic way to strip off the time component in Visual Basic and SQL Server.

Comment: @Dale I know. But that's still how it used to be done before there was a `date` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal conditional aggregation to pivot the rows into one.

But the rest of your query could do with significant simplification

- This doens't need such a complex union anyway. The joins are identical, it just needs a combined `WHERE` condition.
- The `RCD` subquery can be simplified out.
- Looks like most or all of your joins could be `INNER JOIN` instead.
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN Agent A` and `TCD.AgentSkillTargetID IS NOT NULL` are mutually exclusive. Again, it should probably be an `INNER JOIN`, and then you don't need the `IS NOT NULL` condition.

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '2' THEN TCD.DigitsDialed         END) AS OriginalDigitsDialed2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '2' THEN A.EnterpriseName         END) AS OriginalAgentEnterpriseName2, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '2' THEN SG.EnterpriseName        END) AS OriginalAgentSkillGroup2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '2' THEN MS.EnterpriseName        END) AS OriginalScript2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '2' THEN RCD.BeganRoutingDateTime END) AS TransferDateTime2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '2' THEN RCD.DialedNumberString   END) AS TransferDestinationVDN2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '6' THEN TCD.DigitsDialed         END) AS OriginalDigitsDialed6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '6' THEN A.EnterpriseName         END) AS OriginalAgentEnterpriseName6, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '6' THEN SG.EnterpriseName        END) AS OriginalAgentSkillGroup6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '6' THEN MS.EnterpriseName        END) AS OriginalScript6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '6' THEN RCD.BeganRoutingDateTime END) AS TransferDateTime6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN RCD.RequestType = '6' THEN RCD.DialedNumberString   END) AS TransferDestinationVDN6
FROM dbo.Termination_Call_Detail TCD 
JOIN Route_Call_Detail RCD
  ON TCD.RouterCallKeyDay = RCD.RouterCallKeyDay 
 AND TCD.RouterCallKey = RCD.RouterCallKey 
 AND RCD.RouterCallKeySequenceNumber < TCD.RouterCallKeySequenceNumber 
JOIN Agent A 
  ON A.SkillTargetID = TCD.AgentSkillTargetID 
LEFT JOIN Skill_Group SG 
  ON TCD.SkillGroupSkillTargetID = SG.SkillTargetID 
LEFT JOIN Script S
  ON RCD.ScriptID = S.ScriptID
LEFT JOIN Master_Script MS
  ON S.MasterScriptID = MS.MasterScriptID
WHERE TCD.DateTime > @dateFrom 
  AND ((TCD.CallDisposition IN ('28','29') AND RCD.RequestType = '6')
       OR RCD.RequestType = '2')
  AND RCD.DateTime > @dateFrom
  AND RCD.RouterCallKeyDay = '154514'
  AND RCD.RouterCallKey = '2556';
```

Comment: Hi @Charlieface... rather than return the MAX (single) result, am I able to remove the MAX clause and put results in a single row where I have duplicate values of RouterCallKeyDay and RouterCallKey? So basically, one row per RouterCallKey. Been hacking away at this all night with no results. What happens is that half the columns are NULL while the other half have data, but the a lot of these rows have the same RouterCallKey value. Thank You

Comment: Sounds like you need `GROUP BY RouterCallKey` or `GROUP BY RouterCallKey, RouterCallKeyDay` but hard to say without proper sample data and expected results.

Comment: That's essentially a whole new question (it's bad form to completely change the substance of a question after it's been answered). If you have a new question then make a new post for that. Like I said, it looks like you need to put back the `MAX`, but add `GROUP BY RouterCallKey` at the end.

Comment: Hi Charlieface... I applied your logic of re-inserting MAX and using GROUP BY ... I'm almost there it seems. The only problem I'm running into is that the values for TCD.CallDisposition. I'm expecting it to only return those with 28 or 29, but it's also returning records that do not have 28 or 29. Any ideas?

Comment: I was just following the logic you had, which implied you only wanted that filter if `RCD.RequestType = '6'`. but it sounds like you want `AND TCD.CallDisposition IN ('28', '29') AND RCD.RequestType IN ('6', '2')` with no `OR`. Like I said, if you have a new question create a new post.